# Unable to open Unix domain socket

Tags: java, udp, unix-socket

I am trying to listen to UDS, so created UDSSocketClient with socketFile as /tmp/.sock/9001 with socketType = 1, and i get Unable to open Unix domain socket
exception.

```
amonUdsSocket = new UnixDomainSocketClient(socketFile, socketType);
```

Ideally i want to be able to use SOCK_DGRAM but saw tht code was commented on juds. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: did u manage to solve this problem?

Comment: I am using junxsocket 2.5 (agno3)

Comment: ok, i found JUDS to be very good. thanks btw

Comment: but JUDS dont support DATAGRAM right?

Comment: no no, it does support.